# Solving a Viete equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have this equation : $2x^3-7x^2+5x-6=0$
and I have to calculate $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4$ but I don't know the formula of this one.
I know that $S_1 = x_1+x_2+x_3 = -b/a$
$S_2=x_1*x_2+x_1*x_3+x_2*x_3 = c/a$

$S_3 = x_1*x_2*x_3 = -d/a$

and

$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3 = S_1^3 - 3S_1S_2 + 3S_3$

but what about $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4 = ?$

Comment: Did you notice that there is an obvious root for the equation ?

Comment: Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't need to find the root of the equation, I just need to compute $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4$ with the help of Viete equations

Comment: the result should be $\frac{1313}{16}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how do you know ?

Comment: @Macavity I can't figure it out, can you please give me the formula for it ?

Comment: Well you can try learning the method, or looking at the formula http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction+%5Bx%5E4%2By%5E4%2Bz%5E4%2C+%7Bx%2Cy%2Cz%7D%5D&x=0&y=0 Your choice.

Comment: @Macavity finally, thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$3^4+(1/4+1/4\sqrt{15}i)^4+(1/4-1/4\sqrt{15}i)^4=\frac{1313}{16}$$

Comment: it is true, give me your solution

Comment: @CioroianuDenis that should be $s_1^4-4s_1^2s_2+...$

Comment: @CioroianuDenis now you have to check your arithmetic.

Comment: ok i did not downvoted